# Using sed selectively to delete lines

Tags: sed

I have a text file (say file)

```
Name
aaa
bbb
ccc
Name
xxxx
Name
yyyy
tttt
```

I want to remove "Name" from the file except if it occurs in the header. I know `sed` removes lines, but if I do

```
sed '/Name/d' file
```

it removes all "Name".

Desired ouput:

```
Name
aaa
bbb
ccc
xxxx
yyyy
tttt
```

Can you suggest what options I should use?

Comment: First you'd have to explain exactly how you tell "header" apart from "content"...

Comment: Header is the first time the string "Name" occurs. It occurs multiple times because I combined many smaller files all having the header "Name"

Comment: so remove the first line from each file before you combine them. easier to do it there, where you know line 1 is a header. once they're combined, you have absolutely NO way of telling what's a header, and what's content that happens to LOOK like a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
sed '1!{/Name/d}' file
```

The previous command applies to all lines except of the first line.

Comment: you are welcome. keep the `!` operator in mind. It negates conditional expressions in `sed`

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the first header is on the first line, skip it like this:

```
sed '1!{/Name/d}' infile
```

That means the pattern should apply on all lines except line 1.

Or the other way around:

```
sed -n '2,${/Name/d};p' infile
```

Perhaps with `awk`:

```
 awk '/Name/ && c++ == 0 || !/Name/' infile
```

Output in all cases:

```
Name
aaa
bbb
ccc
xxxx
yyyy
tttt
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find the awk syntax more intuitive:

```
awk 'NR==1 || !/Name/' file
```

the above just says `if it's line number 1 or the line doesn't include "Name" then print it`